# What is the difference between "Manually Triggered" and "Individual CI" in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: ssl, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am running into a problem that, Azure DevOps runs without a problem when I trigger manually, but throws error when it runs automatically.
The error is about SSL certificate verification. I use self signed certificate, but I set up the configuration and gave GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY = 1 in pipeline variables.
It must work with this configuration and works when run by manual trigger. But it is giving error when it is run by automated process. Error is:

```
An exception occurred while polling the repository.  Error: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds, Boolean useAnonymousAccess)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds, Boolean useAnonymousAccess)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters, Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2& ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage).
```

Is this a bug of Azure DevOps, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please explain more about your scenario. Are you using Azure DevOps **Server** in conjunction with a self-hosted agent? `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` won't help because this isn't a problem with Git, it's a problem with establishing a TLS connection between your agent and Azure DevOps.

Comment: @DanielMann They are in different servers. And but this works when I trigger manually. I just click on Run Pipeline and it takes me to the Summary page, It works without a problem. Btw this can be generated in Azure Devops Services too.